# changing listview item elements

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm new to Android development. 
I need to make a listview with text and icon audio player. The icon has three States, "download", "downloading", "play" and "pause". The idea is that when populating the listview, set the "download" icon if the track is not downloaded and "play" if the track is downloaded". If a person clicks the "download" button the icon should be updated to "downloading" to start the download, then when complete, you should see the icon "play". If the user presses the "play" icon for this element should be updated to "pause".

I can't change the icon . I tried to change them in onItemClickListener and make the onClick in the getView method in adapter, but when scrolling the icons changed to the old. And if you select multiple items in the list, then change all the icons, and I need to change only one, for playing of the track.

I didn't show the code because there is nothing that can be corrected. - all wrong

Comment: Post your code anyway, because it'll help explaining you what you did wrong. You learn best from understanding what you did wrong instead of only providing the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have your own adapter try using a method notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

That is happening due to recycling of views. If you click on an item and you will see multiple items clicked.
Use RecyclerView instead of listView, which will handle recycling by its own and its ViewHolder class takes care of the issue you are having.
And don't forget to notify the recyclerView adapter whenever you make some change in data source (i.e. arraylist)
Check out this example...
Hope it helps

http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-recyclerview-widget-example/